# Documentation for xhtml pages?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, comments

How can I write good documentation for xhtml jsf pages?

I might use `<!-- comment -->`, but that clutters the code very much, and makes it sometimes more unreadable than without comments.

Is there any way to do HTML comments or inline documentation better?

Comment: Out of every language out there, I'm of the opinion that (X)HTML lends itself most towards [self-documenting code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting). What usecase do you have that depends significant documentation of markup?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but might be an alternative to massive html commenting.

I found that it is much easier (and logical) to document the backing bean methods, than the xhtml itself. The only thing I use the html comment for is to identify large parts/areas on my page so its easier to find.

having readable and well named variables/logic is much better than any comment.